# for Query in DB2 via jdbc not working

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, maximo

I have a query in Maximo which when run via DB visualizer runs fine. but the same query when I run in java via jdbc it throws sql exception.
The query is a bit different than usual and is shown below.

It gives the next sequence number for the next entry.

```
select nextval for mytabledseq from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: Remove the line of code that says `throw new SQLException();`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. I had to add the schema name before mytableseq. 
e.g. MAXIMO.mytableseq now it works fine